# facebook graph api '{user-id/feed/}'doesn't show feed properly

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get feed of friends whose are in the my friend list ({me/friends})

I have right permissions to do that. (user_friends and read_stream)

But the result of api doesn't show feeds of my friends properly ({user-id/feed})

To be exact, the result feeds are the part of the real feed.

What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the feed of friends specific to the friends list, but you can get the user's stream / home feed using:

```
/me/home
```

It shows all the posts by friends, pages, etc. In comparison, `/me/feed` shows what the user has posted.